# Connect PHP 5.6 application hosted by MAMP Pro 4.2 to MySQL 8, Local host setup (127.0.0.1) on Windows 10

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, workbench, mamp-pro

*Salam and Greetings,*

MySQL 8 which installed along with Workbench 8 was configured to work with port # 3307, as the port # 3306 was reserved by MAMP Pro for its own instance of MySQL ver 5.7

I was able to connect my PHP applications that was hosted on an older version of MAMP Pro version 4.1 (i guess) using the below shown connection setup *1

After upgrading to Mamp Pro 4.2, the PHP application failed to access MySQL 8

At this point, MySQL 8 database was still working fine and accessible using Workbench 8,

After several unsuccessful attempts which include re-installation of Workbench 8, MySQL 8 and even MAMP Pro 4.2, I've reset the whole computer and carried out fresh installation of Workbench and MAMP Pro but the issue still persist and the PHP Application still can't access MySQL 8

I've logged this incident to MAMP Pro tow days back but no one yet back to me

I appreciate if someone would suggest a solution to host My PHP on any web-server that allows smooth connection with MySQL 8 (preferable to be MAMP Pro on Windows 10 as I already have a purchased license)

Kindest regards,

*1 PHP connection file:

```
        $host="127.0.0.1";
        $port=3307;
        $socket="";
        $user="root";
        $password="password";
        $dbname="kaf";

        $con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
        or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

        //$con->close();
```

Comment: what is the exact error message? Edit this in your question.

Comment: Dear danblack: No error messages shown just the queries are no longer work, i think the PHP code can't access the database (i.e. MySQL ver 8), but for information the code can connect to MySQL 5.7 that bundled with MAMP Pro using port 3306

Comment: Look harder. Look for [error] logs. Without detail it could just be guessing at the answer. If the Pro support isn't going to answer without detail don't expect much better here. Backing to reinstalling everything without and understanding of what when wrong isn't going to help you learn anything in your programming/IT development. Details matter, "no longer work" can mean significant multitude of things. Be specific.

Comment: Will try to find out where those php error log files, thank you danblack. I Also totally agree with you about the need for trying everything before reset, but i had to do so for some complication faced to reset root password which enforced me to make a fresh installation of everything